# Apache exit with code 0 docker apache attempt

Tags: php, apache, docker, fedora, lamp

I currently have a problem running my apache web-server successfully while using Docker...

Here is my docker file:

```
FROM fedora:27

# Container Owner
MAINTAINER nzhiti@gmail.com

# Update & install Apache & clean dnf
RUN dnf upgrade -y 
RUN dnf install -y httpd
RUN dnf clean packages
RUN dnf install -y mod_ssl

# Configuring hosts
ADD ./hosts/hosts /etc/hosts


# Port 
EXPOSE 443

# Starting httpd
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/httpd"] & CMD ["-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

No errors during building. But when I try to compose it, it never works, and the only message outputted is `apache exiting with code 0`

```
version: '3'
services:
    php-apache:
        image : httpd_fedora
        ports:
            - 443:443
        volumes:
            - ./Apache/www/:/var/www/html
            - ./Apache/vhosts/:/etc/httpd/conf.d/
            - ./Apache/SSLcert/:/etc/httpd/ssl/
            - ./Apache/errorlogs/error.log:/var/log/httpd/error.log
    tty: true
```

I'm out of ideas...

Thanks,
DRK

Answer (score 0):

Try indenting `tty: true` so it's aligned with `php_apache` properties. Also copy the `Dockerfile` to the same directory of `docker-compose.yml`, and change `image` to `build: .`.

```
version: '3'
services:
    php-apache:
        build: .
        ports:
            - 443:443
        volumes:
            - ./Apache/www/:/var/www/html
            - ./Apache/vhosts/:/etc/httpd/conf.d/
            - ./Apache/SSLcert/:/etc/httpd/ssl/
            - ./Apache/errorlogs/error.log:/var/log/httpd/error.log
        tty: true
```

Comment: First of all thanks the reply.
I've the modifications, here is what's cames out :

    ERROR: for ........ : Cannot start service php-apache: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container proccess caused "exec: \"httpd-foreground\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

This time It seems apache didn't even start.
Thanks,
DRK

Comment: You're welcome. Are you calling `docker-compose up --build` in the same dir as Dockerfile ?

Comment: Oops sorry completely forgot,  mybad ! Here what comes : ERROR: for omnialib_php-apache_1  Cannot create container for service php-apache: invalid volume specification: '0217e6460afbf90ab63efb36d22b88b790bc7280a8dd5f0d68bec7143b854914:vhosts:rw': invalid mount config for type "volume": invalid mount path: 'vhosts' mount path must be absolute

Comment: Volume paths must be absolute. `/path/to/Apache` instead of `./Apache`

Comment: Well, same error as the begining, exit code 0. No way to get a log ?

Comment: I guess you have given up on this ? Did you check the logs ?